What is the Relationship Between Shakti, Prana and Akasha?
I don't consider myself knowledgeable in Hinduism, but it seems to me that shakti would be Brahman in its active aspect, a kind of universal energy with which everything was created. I have read that prana would be the expression of shakti in the physical body. Some use the term Prana Shakti. Would that be correct?
Regarding akasha, I understand it to be something like space, the "matter" of all the dimensions that make up the universe. Did Brahman create akasha through shakti?

Shakti would be Brahman in its active aspect?
Brahman has no definition, so the Sages described it in a single word: PURNAM (Whole). The Students further enquired it's qualities. So the Sages said:
Anantam (Without Beginning or End/ Infinite)
Shivam (unblemished/un-stained auspiciousness)
Satyam (Truth)
Cit (Self-aware, Consciousness, Oneness .... there is not English term)
Sat (To - be)
Ananda (non-polar state of Bliss. To be in bliss with oneself)
This Brahman (that is Infinite), has infinite possibilities. One such possibility is our existence as an individual. Like walking in a street with visibility limited to the objects in the line of sight, compared to viewing the same street from an elevation (flying in a helicopter) where you can see much more.
For an individual, the term "Inifite" is not comprehensible. So, Sages divided the knowing (Jignasu)  of "Cit" into "Cit of Ananda" and "Cit of Shakti".
Shakti = That which resonates. Like an electron. It's there and it's not there. It is a particle and it is a wave. All of creation (Sristi), and its realities (Jagath), and its Elemental Creation (Prapancha) and its witness the Soul (Jiva). Cumulatively called Prakriti, and its nature is Illusive (Maya). Its owner is Purusha who is self-dependent (Ishvara).
Prana is a tether (a string or air - Vayu) that holds both the Soul (jiva) with the physical body (upadhi), that constantly enters and exits. If it enters but doesn't leave or if it leaves but doesn't enter, then the tether is gone. Anything that changes or moves is an attribute of Shakti.
Akasha: is the blank canvas, that is devoid of any flavor, in which the attributes of Shakti is witnessed by an individual in the form of all aspected defined above under Shakti.
All the above are Sanskrit terms with definitions found in any good Dictionary or Wisdom Library.
Here is the source link
Source link 2

"Shakti would be Brahman in its active aspect?"
Words from Ramakrisnha:
"When I think of the Supreme Being as inactive - neither creating nor preserving nor destroying -, I call Him Brahman or Purusha, the Impersonal God. When I think of Him as active - creating, preserving, and destroying -, I call Him Śakti or Māyā or Prakriti, the Personal God."
Source: "The Gospel of Ramakrishna".

A person speaking "on-behalf" of Brahman is different from a Sage explaining their student. This literature is very precise and covers many subtle aspects, hence we have a diverse vocabulary, like Samisti-Jiva, Ishavara, Avatara, Amsha, Purusha, Brahman, Paramatma, Deva and more.. These terms are not to be intermixed, unless you are not an explorer. if you are a devotee then you should just go by what a Guru says. But if you are an explorer then Sanatana Culture has an ocean of literature. However, I gave you a very precise definition for each. Its up to you to choose what works best for you.
